# Count from a queue using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, count

Ive been trying to invoke a count property on a queue. Ive tried all sorts of invoking. How do I get the int value of the count, from the count of a queue?

The syntax im trying to use but doesnt work is

(ConsoleKey)Dequeue.Invoke(InputQueue, new object[] { });

The correct syntax is:
  var queueObj = InputQueue.GetMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[] { });

```
      public class ReflectionAttempts
        {
            Type magicType;
            object magicClassObject;
            MethodInfo UpdateView;
            PropertyInfo InputQueue;
            PropertyInfo Count;
            MethodInfo Dequeue;
            public ReflectionAttempts(Type magicType)
            {
                this.magicType = magicType;
                magicClassObject = Activator.CreateInstance(magicType);
                InputQueue = magicType.GetProperty("InputQueue");
                Count = InputQueue.PropertyType.GetProperty("Count");
                Dequeue = InputQueue.PropertyType.GetMethod("Dequeue");
                var queueObj =  InputQueue.GetMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[] { });

                int theCount = (int) Count.GetMethod.Invoke(queueObj, new object[] { });
                Input abc = (Input)  Dequeue.Invoke(queueObj, new object[] { });

            }
        }
```

Comment: You cannot use `InputQueue` as the argument to `Invoke` as it's a `PropertyInfo`. You should get the value of the `InputQueue` property by getting its Get method and invoking it on the object. Something like `var queueObj = InputQueue.GetMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{})`, then use `queueObj` instead: `Dequeue.Invoke(queueObj, ...);`

Comment: If you answer this, ill mark it as the correct answer. Thanks alot. I didnt know if what I was doing was going to work. It works. So Now I have this as an option if I want to do it like this. Because now I can load whatever crap I want into this program... :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad it worked for you, here it goes as an answer:

You cannot use `InputQueue` as the argument to `Invoke` as it's a `PropertyInfo`. You should get the value of the `InputQueue`property by getting its Get method and invoking it on the object. Something like

```
var queueObj = InputQueue.GetMethod.Invoke(magicClassObject, new object[]{})
```

then use `queueObj` instead:

```
Dequeue.Invoke(queueObj, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially it's:

```
PropertyInfo piCount = ...;
var count = (int)piCount.GetValue(InputQueue);
```

But I'd strongly recommend to re-design this in such way when you don't need to use reflection (if possible). That's not a good design, slow, hard to implement and maintain.

Like this:

```
class GameStateMachine<T> where T : GameViewMachine
{
}

abstract class GameViewMachine
{
  public int Count { get; }
  public IQueue InputQueue { get; }
}
```

Comment: I probably will redesign it. I want to be able to hook up any kind of view, without knowing what sort of inputs it wants. thats why I decided to try using reflection. Let me try your code there.

Comment: I get the error: _COMPlusExceptionCode = -532462766

Comment: But now I have to specify the type of machine somewhere. If I just got the queue working via reflection. I wouldnt have to.

Comment: What if I just use the dynamic keyword so that I can specify T at runtime.